AioRTC one-way video call error in python
when i try to run this code:
server.py:
    import asyncio
import cv2
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, VideoStreamTrack
from aiohttp import web
from pyngrok import ngrok
class OpenCVVideoStreamTrack(VideoStreamTrack):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            raise RuntimeError("Nu s-a putut deschide camera video. Verifică conexiunea la cameră.")

    async def recv(self):
        frame = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, self._get_frame)
        return frame

    def _get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if not ret:
            raise RuntimeError("Eroare la capturarea cadrelor video.")
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return frame

pcs = set()
async def offer(request):
    params = await request.json()
    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    pcs.add(pc)
    video_track = None
    if cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened():
        video_track = OpenCVVideoStreamTrack()
        video_track.direction = "sendrecv"
        pc.addTrack(video_track)
    else:
        return web.Response(status=500, text="Eroare la inițializarea camerei. Camera nu este disponibilă.")

    @pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
    async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
        print(f"ICE connection state: {pc.iceConnectionState}")
        if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
            await pc.close()
            pcs.discard(pc)

    if "sdp" not in params or "type" not in params:
        return web.Response(status=400, text="Oferta este invalidă.")

    offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])
    await pc.setRemoteDescription(offer)
    answer = await pc.createAnswer()
    await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
    return web.json_response(
        {"sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp, "type": pc.localDescription.type}
    )

async def cleanup(app):
    for pc in pcs:
        await pc.close()
    pcs.clear()

app = web.Application()
app.on_shutdown.append(cleanup)
app.router.add_post("/offer", offer)
public_url = ngrok.connect(8080)
print(f"Ngrok public URL: {public_url}")
web.run_app(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

web.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WebRTC Stream</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Live Stream</h1>
  <video id="video" autoplay playsinline controls></video>
  <script>
    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    const serverUrl = "https://8941-93-117-166-235.ngrok-free.app/offer"; // Înlocuiește cu URL-ul public ngrok

    async function start() {
      const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

      pc.ontrack = (event) => {
        video.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      };
      const offer = await pc.createOffer();
      await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
      const response = await fetch(serverUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription),
        mode: "no-cors" // Asigură-te că CORS este permis
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error("Eroare la trimiterea ofertei");
        return;
      }
      const answer = await response.json();
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }
    start().catch(err => {
      console.error("Eroare în start():", err);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

**I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 480, in _handle_request
resp = await request_handler(request)
File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 569, in _handle
return await handler(request)
File "/home/andrei/Desktop/tekwill_ai_project/server.py", line 65, in offer
await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiortc/rtcpeerconnection.py", line 792, in setLocalDescription
t._setCurrentDirection(and_direction(t.direction, t._offerDirection))
File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiortc/rtcpeerconnection.py", line 259, in and_direction
return sdp.DIRECTIONS[sdp.DIRECTIONS.index(a) & sdp.DIRECTIONS.index(b)]
ValueError: None is not in list
and i dont know how to get rid of this, i want to create an ngrok server that sends real time video from opencv to a website, can please someone help, it is my first time using aiortc or webrtc?
**

I'm also facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?
